# No puedo usar los modulos registrados de la store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Tengo el siguiente modulo;

**store/modules/Snackbar.js**

```
const snackbar = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        snackbar: {
            show: false,
            message: "",
            color: "",
            top: null,
            bottom: null,
            multiLine: true,
        }
    },
}

export default snackbar;
```

En mi store **store/main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import snackbar from './modules/Snackbar'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules:{
    snackbar
  },
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

Cuando intento acceder al state de mi modulo desde un componente no me funciona como se supone deberia;

**Componente**

```
import { login } from "@/api/Auth.api";

export default {
  mounted() {
     console.log(this.$store.state.snackbar.snackbar);
  },
}
```

En la consola:

`[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'snackbar' of undefined"`

He leído la documentación, otros sitios y ni siquiera registrando un modulo local en la misma store funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solucion, en mi store tengo `modules` duplicado, esta al inicio de la store y al final, esto al parecer sobre escribe los modulos;

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import snackbar from './modules/Snackbar'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules:{
    snackbar
  },
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: { } // Quitar esto!
})
```

Comment: PD: Pase 2 horas y media con este problema, por eso decidí crear la pregunta. Da la casualidad que unos minutos después de publicada la pregunta, encontrara la respuesta...